# PythonのMultiprocessingでArray型の共有メモリの要素数を可変にする方法

Tags: python

次のようなコードを試してみました。

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process, Lock

def process1(array,  lock):
    with lock:
        buffer_data = str("z1111").encode("utf-8")
        array[0:len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = Array('c', 35)
    lock = Lock()

    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[array, lock], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test1.join()
    
    print(array[:].decode("utf-8"))
    print("process ended")
```

実行すると、次のメッセージが出力されて問題なく動作しました。

```
z1111
process ended
```

しかし、次のように、buffer_dataが35byteより大きくなると、エラーになります。

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process, Lock

def process1(array,  lock):
    with lock:
        buffer_data = str("z1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111").encode("utf-8")
        array[0:len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = Array('c', 35)
    lock = Lock()

    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[array, lock], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test1.join()
    
    print(array[:].decode("utf-8"))
    print("process ended")
```

エラー内容は次の通りです。

```
ValueError: Can only assign sequence of same size
```

配列の長さを関数内で自由に変更するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

また、配列の長さを長めに確保しておくことは可能かと思いますが、文字列を短くしたい場合などに、配列を1度リセット/クリアしてから短い文字列を入力することは可能でしょうか？

次の例だと、`z22`とprintしたいのに、`z2211`とprintされてしまいます。

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Array, Process, Lock

def process1(array,  lock):
    with lock:
        buffer_data = str("z1111").encode("utf-8")
        array[0:len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = Array('c', 35)
    lock = Lock()

    process_test1 = Process(target=process1, args=[array, lock], daemon=True)
    
    process_test1.start()
    process_test1.join()

    buffer_data = str("z22").encode("utf-8")
    array[0:len(buffer_data)] = buffer_data[:]

    print(array[:].decode("utf-8"))
    print("process ended")
```

Comment: `multiprocessing.Array` は初期化の際に指定した長さ(size)を変更することができません。(固定長オブジェクト) 可変長オブジェクトが必要であれば [multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) を利用するとよいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。長さは変更することができないのですね。その点に関しては、長めに配列を作っておけば何とかなりそうです。質問文を編集してみたのですが、配列を短く上書きしたい場合にもクリアする方法がわからなくて困っています。このような場合は対処方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 専用のメソッドがあるのかもしれませんが、`with lock: array[:] = [0]*len(array)` としてもよいかと。

Comment: もしよければ、そちらご回答ください。

Comment: 回答に転記しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※ コメントから転記

> また、配列の長さを長めに確保しておくことは可能かと思いますが、文字列を短くしたい場合などに、配列を1度リセット/クリアしてから短い文字列を入力することは可能でしょうか？

専用のメソッドがあるのかもしれませんが、以下の様にしてもよいかと思います。

```py
with lock:
    array[:] = [0]*len(array)
```

なお、`array[:]` の場合は配列全体の内容になりますので、`array.value`(null terminator までの値)とする方がよろしいかと思います。

```
print(array[:].decode("utf-8"))
# z22^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
print(array.value.decode("utf-8"))
# z22
```